# window popup instead of dialog box in single selected row in primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I wanna use popup window instead of dialog box in primefaces. How to call popup window event in .I call window popup in jquery funcution but jquery don't know id="cars" of p:dataTable.How to call the row of p:dataTable from jquery.Look at my code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
     $('#cars tr').dblclick(
        function() {
              var securities_id = $(this).attr('id');           
              window.showModalDialog("/view/Login Entry Input.html");       
         });
   });
</script>


<h:form id="form">

<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>

<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"
             selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single">

   <!--  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
                update=":form:display :form:growl" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowUnselect}" update=":form:growl"/> -->

    <f:facet name="header">
        Select a row to display a message
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Model">
        #{car.model}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        #{car.year}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" >
        #{car.manufacturer}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        #{car.color}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: put a comma between params. `window.showModalDialog("/view/Login", "Entry");`

Comment: This is complete code for window popup. window.showModalDialog("/view/Login Entry Input.html","Dialog Box Arguments # 1","dialogHeight: 565px; dialogWidth: 609px; dialogTop: 0px; dialogLeft: 0px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: no; status: Yes;"); I think jquery don't know id="cars" of p:datatable.

Comment: <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
                update=":form:display :form:growl" /> How to call window popup in <p:ajax/> or another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--***********************************************************************
 * $Date: 2013-11-13 $
 * $Author:  [Zayar Htet] $
 * $Rev 1.0 $
 * Copyright (c) 2013 DIR-ACE Technology Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
 ***********************************************************************-->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/layout/commonTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="head">
        <script src="../javascript/tdLo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        var  count = 0;     

    $(function(){
            $(document.getElementById('form:cars_data')).on('click', '.ui-datatable-selectable', function(){

                timerID = setInterval(function(){               
                if( document.getElementById("form:test").value != "dd" )    {               
                    window.showModalDialog("http://localhost:8080/sts/view/OrderQuote.seam","Dialog Box Arguments # 1","dialogHeight: 565px; dialogWidth: 609px; dialogTop: 0px; dialogLeft: 0px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: no; status: Yes;");
                    clearInterval(timerID);
                    timerID = null;
                    }

                },200)
                ;

                });
            });  

    </script>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="title">
        <!-- Screen title label-->
        List of Product
    </ui:define>
    <div>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form id="form">

                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

                <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car"
                    value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" rows="10"
                    selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
                        immediate="true" update=":form:test" />

                    <p:column headerText="Model">
                        #{car.model}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Year">
           #{car.year}
        </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">
            #{car.manufacturer}
        </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Color">
            #{car.color}
        </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

                <h:inputHidden id="test" value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}" style="diplay:none;"/>
            </h:form>


        </ui:define>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

This is my complete code for p:datatable selected row with popup window.
1.If clicked row , table row select javascript function run 
2.I use setInterval for waiting the p:ajax listener event finished(to select db data) and bind my data into my show page.
3.immediate="true" in p:ajax change h:inputhidden value.
4.If h:inputhidden value change , setInterval method show my window popup. :)